# sql query to split based on the delimiter and compare with others

Tags: postgresql

I have a table `test_data` as:

```
Studentid       type       value
    1           height     class:sixth|heightInCm:135
    2           height     class:sixth|heightInCm:127
    3           height     class:seventh|heightInCm:142
    4           height     class:seventh|heightInCm:100
    5           weight     class:sixth|WeightInKg:26
    6           weight     class:sixth|WeightInKg:32
    7           weight     class:seventh|WeightInKg:38
    8           weight     class:seventh|WeightInKg:40
```

I have another table named as `Rule_table` as :

```
type    operator    value       score
height  AND(=,>=)   sixth|125     1
height  AND(=,>=)   seventh|135   1
weight  AND(=,>=)   sixth|35      1
weight  AND(=,>=)   seventh|40    1
```

meaning of this row `height  AND(=,>=)   sixth|125     1` in the `rule_table` is : if `class = sixth` AND `heightInCm >= 125` then score will be 1 else zero . Like this all the rows can be understood. so in operator columns it's the order of operator with And  and which will be checked with the value.

After applying this `rule_table` to the `test_data` table we can get a table like as:

```
Studentid       type       value                            score
    1           height     class:sixth|heightInCm:135        1
    2           height     class:sixth|heightInCm:127        1
    3           height     class:seventh|heightInCm:142      1 
    4           height     class:seventh|heightInCm:100      0
    5           weight     class:sixth|WeightInKg:36         1 
    6           weight     class:sixth|WeightInKg:32         0
    7           weight     class:seventh|WeightInKg:38       0
    8           weight     class:seventh|WeightInKg:40       1
```

I am struggling into Writing the query. If it were single valued and single operator then i would have done it easily. But for multi valued and multi operator it's being difficult for me.

can any one please help me on the same. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: What you call `value` are actually **two values** . Before doing anything else, first learn about the first normal form: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Comment: That's right what you are saying. But this is sample data. Here it's not making sense to have data like this. That's why you are suggesting first normal form to represent the data in a better fashion. But the data which i have is slightly different. So if i get the logic from here the i can apply this logic to my original data to get the desired result. So Please suggest the query for this if possible. Thanks.